# Is assuming spacetime to have |2^N| points overkill?

Tags: mathematical-physics

The physical continuum is commonly assumed to have a mathematical continuum of points, that is, with a cardinality equinumerous with the Power Set of the set of natural numbers. However, since 
[ZFC + "there exists an inaccessible cardinal"] 
suffices to model analysis, and
[ZFC + "there exists an inaccessible cardinal"+ the negation of the continuum hypothesis] 
is equiconsistent with the former,
but that the existence of aleph-one is a useful assumption (Borel sets, etc.),
wouldn't it be more appropriate to assume only that space-time has (at least) a cardinality of aleph-one?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), e.g. `$2^{\aleph_0}$` becomes $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: When you quantize space and time, there will probably not be a continuum of points. Nobody truly understands a theory of quantum space-time yet, but there are good reasons for believing that such a theory exists.

Comment: If and when we have a theory that deals adequately with a quantized space-time, one can perhaps discard a lot of the present theory (although I suspect that much of it will still be kept for convenience). However, until such time, physical theories in place still deal with a continuum $2^{\aleph_0}$ of points rather than $\aleph_1$, and my question remains valid.